# How to create django subdomains

Tags: python, django

How will I create django `subdomains` for user accounts that can return user information even if the user isn't logged in. For example `jane.website.com` returns jane's page even though jane isn't logged in. I have tried `django-subdomains` but it keeps giving me this error:

> Module not found error :No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'.

I am pretty sure the error is from `django-subdomains` so I rather use something else. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is only partly related to programming. The main work will be to configure a webserver infront of Django to handle the subdomains. Then you just have to evaluate the hostname from the request.

Comment: I created a local host and then linked it to a domain name that is running on my system  by editing the hosts file.Now the domain is http://www.testing.local:8000/, so I should be able to make django subdomains work with that if that's what you mean.

Comment: You need to configre a webserver like nginx or caddy to rewrite transparent (The client does not see them) the subdomains to an url in django wich returns the user information `jane.example.com -> example.com:8000/users/jane`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.core.urlresolvers` module was removed in Django 2.0 and it was moved to `django.urls`. `django-subdomains` does not apply these changes. So `ImportError` raised. See [this issue](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains/issues/69).

This issue opend in jule 2018, but maintainer didn't fix that. And there has been no commit since 2016. So I think this library is not maintained.

Your choice:

- Find another library.
- Downgrade your django version.
- Wait with hope